# What do Sam and Die-Hardman mean by 'No rest for the wicked' and 'idle hands and all that'?

Tags: death-stranding

Could you explain this quote from Death Stranding:

> Sam: No rest for the wicked, huh.
>
> Die-Hardman: Yeah, well, idle hands and all that. We’ll give you the details at the dispatch terminal. Make sure you check it upstairs. Drop’s waiting up there, too.

How are 'no rest for the wicked' and 'idle hands' related?

Comment: The full saying is "idle hands are the devil's workshop" (or "devil's playthings/playground/tools") if that helps!

Comment: "no rest" -> "they're keeping us busy"; "idle hands" -> "so we don't get into mischief"

Comment: I've heard it as "The devil finds work for idle hands to do".

Comment: [The Phrase Finder site](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-devil-makes-work-for-idle-hands.html#:~:text='The%20devil%20makes%20work%20for%20idle%20hands'%20is%20one%20of,arises%20from%20not%20keeping%20busy.) cites *The Indicator*, February 1848, for this proverb's customary English form.

Comment: I always thought the "idle hands" saying was supposed to be a euphemism for something else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "no rest for the wicked" is based on Isaiah chapter 48 verse 20 and chapter 57 verses 20 and 21:

> 20 But the wicked are like the troubled sea, when it cannot rest,
> whose waters cast up mire and dirt.
>
> 21 There is no peace, saith my God, to the wicked.

The assertion at Dictionary.com that the verse refers to eternal torment is not supported by the context or by any Bible commentary of which I am aware.

The actual idea Isaiah expresses in his book is that humans will have a better life if they allow God to guide them. To illustrate, here are verses 17 through 19 of chapter 48:

> This is what the Lord says—
> your Redeemer, the Holy One of Israel:
> “I am the Lord your God,
> who teaches you what is best for you,
> who directs you in the way you should go.
> If only you had paid attention to my commands,
> your peace would have been like a river,
> your well-being like the waves of the sea.
> Your descendants would have been like the sand,
> your children like its numberless grains;
> their name would never be blotted out
> nor destroyed from before me.”

So those who follow God's advice for life as conveyed through prophets such as Isaiah will prosper. In contrast, the "wicked" (defined as those who sin by doing such things as worshiping idols or engaging in dishonest business practices) will experience unnecessary troubles in life. It is in this sense that there is no peace for them.

Within Christianity the view is that all humans are sinners, just some more than others. As the Apostle Paul says "All have sinned and fallen short of the glory of God." (Romans 3:23). So even a believer could experience self-inflicted troubles due to failure to apply Biblical advice for stress-free living. Until well into the 20th century the average person would have been familiar with these ideas whether they were a believing Christian or not.

So the phrase "no rest for the wicked" is a self deprecating suggestion that whatever new difficulty has arisen is a consequence of the speaker's own failure to organize and conduct their life in the best way.

Answer (score 27):

[No rest for the wicked](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/no-rest-wicked/) is a quote from the Christian Bible indicating that the damned will suffer eternal torment, but it's commonly used in idiomatic speech to indicate that work never ends. When you complete one task, another is given to you.

The reference to idle hands is, as Kitkat notes, is more semi-religious, [dating back to about the 14th century in the clearer forms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idle_hands_are_the_devil%27s_workshop), referring to the idea that if you don't keep busy, the devil will find work for them. It's basically an injunction that if you aren't working, you find yourself more prone to vice since you don't have better things to do with your time.

So here, it basically comes down to Sam complaining that he's overworked and Die-Hardman replying back that keeping busy is a good thing because it keeps you out of trouble, somewhat clouded by that they're both [bromides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromide_(language)), phrases that are so over-used that they have no real meaning other than that people expect you to say them.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idle_hands_are_the_devil%27s_workshop for more Idle Hands references.

Comment: "Idle minds are the Devil's workshop" is a similar phrase